# I have canceled my AdSense account. Can I apply for a new account?

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies, accounts

I recently canceled my AdSense account and I want to re-apply for a new one, with a different email.

My payee name and other informations will be exactly the same as my canceled account. Can I open a new AdSense account using the same information? My previous account no longer exists.

If I can, how long I have to wait after canceling it?

Answer (score 1):

Gracey addresses this question in the [Google Product Forums](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/adsense/Y1XBQsDo1vE/zRpjuce7g40J)

> If your Adsense account was cancelled, then you can only reapply for a new AdSense account using a completely NEW Google account and NEW gmail account.
>
> You can't sign up again with any account you previously used.

So you cannot use the same Google account or email address. I have not seen anything that says that there would be a waiting period.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can apply for a new account, so that you have a new mail ID and a new bank account. 
Google Adsense blocks our account only when we do not work according to its guidelines.

Answer (score -1):

I guess, if you have already cancelled your account, you can reapply - even with the same (or different) email id and same bank account details.

Adsense policy just require you to have atmost one account and it seems, you now have none and so can surely apply.